# How do I find where an HttpURLConnection is trying to redirect me to?

Tags: java, http, redirect, httpurlconnection

I have an HttpURLConnection that I do not what to follow redirects, however if a redirect appears I want to know where I would get redirected to. There doesn't seem to be a method of HttpURLConnection that will show me that, is there any way I can get that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the Header "Location", it contains the URL where you are redirected. Look at the HTTP spec for all the details

Answer (score 1):

First turn of redirect follows:

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

conn being your HTTPConnection variable. Then read the Location header.