# how to check if URL has been redirected without opening browser tests

Tags: java

I want to check if http://www.google.com/pid/596978 redirects to http://www.google.com/cd/en/pid/596978. Is there any possibilities to check that without opening browser.

sample code:

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.curry.com/pid/596978");
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
huc.connect();
System.out.println(huc.getURL());
int code = huc.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(code);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591511/how-do-i-find-where-an-httpurlconnection-is-trying-to-redirect-me-to

Comment: Thanks a lot for redirecting.